# DialogFragment opening Database, DatabaseLocked

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialogfragment that I use for the user to input information into.  when the user clicks ok the info is passed back to the main activity through an interface where I attempt to put it into a database.
this is the dialog positive click code:

```
     .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnclickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
         name = edittextname.getText().toString();
         details = edittextdetails.getText().toString();

         bundle.putString("name", name);
         bundle.putString("detail", detail);

         mListener.OnAddInfo(Bundle);
```

and on the mainactivity I implemented the interface and this in code:

```
    public void OnAddInfo(Bundle bundle){
         name = bundle.getString("name");
         detail = bundle.getString("detail");

    db.open();
    long id = db.insertInfo(name, detail);
    db.close();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Added " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I know the data is being passed through because when I comment out the db parts the toast comes up correctly. I don't think there is a problem with my db because in other activities not using a dialogfragment it works fine.  The error msg i get is this:

```
      FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      java.lang.NullPointerException at
      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
      .getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
```

I have tried many things to fix this and just cant figure it out.  Is this just something that isnt allowed or am I just missing something?  The mainactivity is also a fragmentactivity.

Comment: I figured out a way of getting the data into the database.  I don't know if its good coding but it is the only way that it has worked.

I put a startactivityforresult() in the mainactivity portion of the code that I pass bundle too and insert the info in the new activity.

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours on this and gave up, only to accidentally discover a solution. Declaring the new database at the beginning of the DialogFragment class where you usually declare stuff doesn't work, but declaring it inside the onCreateDialog method works!

Example:

onCreateDialog(){

DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

// use db now with no lock.

}